# Validations doesn't exist on Resources when publishing

Tags: c#, resources, umbraco

I have an Umbraco solution, where i have installed a plugin called PageComments. 
Everything works locally. 
But when i publish and throw it up on the server, i get an error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Validations' does not exist in the namespace 'Resources' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Line 51:             {
Line 52:                 //If model is not valid or Not able to find pageId or Invalid Captcha return error message.
Line 53:                 returnMessage = Resources.Validations.CommentPostedFailure;
Line 54:                 return Content(returnMessage);
Line 55:             }
```

I have tried looking for a dll to add in references but, have been unable to find a correct one...

I am a bit stumped.. And have googled for answers to no avail so far.

Comment: If it's an issue related to that plugin it would be better if you contact the developer directly: https://www.gajadigital.com/en/umbraco/how-to-install-page-comments-plugin.

Comment: @MarioLopez i don't know if it is. The plugin works perfectly on my local machine...

Comment: Have you installed it as umbraco package or as nuget?

Comment: @MarioLopez i added it as a package in the developer section

Comment: Then check that when you are publishing your project the dll is being copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed an entire folder wasn't being published. Global resources.
When this was added, the website worked again.